# javascript datepicker - dates the same - but duration needs to be "1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

when datepicker end date has the same date as the start date, the total_days returns a value of "0".  would I perhaps be able to place a "+1" in the code to allow this value to be "1" for the "total_days" when the two dates are the same?

```
var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if( days >= 0 ) {
    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
    }
}


$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);
```

Comment: that sounds right...where could i insert that?  (thank you)

Comment: Right before `if( days >= 0 ) {` should work.

Comment: thank you.  will that affect the "negative issue".  -  I inserted that "if( days >= 0 ) {" code to prevent the user from being able to have the end date before the start date - otherwise the value becomes "0"   ?

Comment: Nope. It just checks to see if the days value is zero and if so, changes it to 1. If it's less than zero it does nothing.

Comment: great! it is working lovely - thank you.      another question (if you dont mind)  :  : is there a way to prevent the "end date" from being selected if it is before the "start date".   it is no longer showing as a negative, but i see it is still allowing the calculation...?

Comment: Sure, have you checked out the date range example of the datepicker? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: I have "tried", but cannot seem to get it to work.  I will keep trying.  thank you very much for your help